# SharePoint quick launch edit links having issue in some pages

Tags: sharepoint-server, quick-launch

In some pages, the quick launch editing is not working.I am not able to change element position, nor able to remove existing links.

All links have a x next to it .

[image]

-tried to set master page to default, still same issue.

-created a new blank page without any jQuery, still has the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint, and i can reproduce your issue when i edit quick launch link in publishing page.

Deactivate the SharePoint Server Publishing site feature solved the issue:

Navigate to site settings->Manage site features->Deactivate the SharePoint Server Publishing site feature.

Comment: But i need custom master page and navigation,i suppose to use design manager we need to enable  publishing feature

Comment: on further research found a user having similar issue: 
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/128419/quicklaunch-menu-edit-links-not-working-on-publishing-pages-sharepoint-2013 .. but no solution

Comment: You can change the master page from URL, or change the master page, then deactivate the SharePoint Server Publishing site feature. You can use design manager after deactivate the SharePoint Server Publishing site feature.